# Play Back values based on csv data

Tags: python-3.x, excel, image, csv

Python 3.5 currently being used/learned or if another option would work better please advise.

Hello, I have a .csv file with information in it that i am trying to convert into a graphical representation.

DateTime,x7.y1.value,x7.y2.value,x7.y3.value,x7.y4.value,Unlatch.value

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

1/19/2016 5:43,0,1,1,1,1

I already have a background image. background.jpg and a green dot. greendot.jpg that i will be using.

I am looking for some guidance on how to do a few things or what my options are.
I do know i can read the .csv file into either a list or a dictionary. I am still trying to figure out which way would be best for me. I have found tutorials on how to read the csv file into each so i can make that work at least...

How can i make these images play back on screen using this timeline? if i open this in excel it shows me the dates down to the second, when i open it in notepad ++ it shows it how i have it a listed above with out the seconds.

Is there a technical name for a play back bar/button that way i can read up on this?

What I would ultimately like to do is Load a csv file, and then be able to play back (second by second or row by row) with a slider bar and a play button so that i can see an image (greendot.jpg) turn on when the value is 1 and off when the value is 0.

So...at 1/19/2016 5:43:01 the first Greendot.jpg is (off) the second, third, fourth and fifth greendot.jpg are (on) then those same dots get re-evaluated at 1/19/2016 5:43:02.

Any pointers to reading material would be great since i do not know the technical names or terms that would be used or i would have looked those up.